# Conflict between LED driver and analog to digital conversion on Arduino

Tags: c, arduino, microcontroller, spi, atmega

On the Arduino Nano V3, I am trying to get an LED driver (TLC5960) and two analog to digital (ADC) converters (MCP3208) to work together.  The LED driver is on the same pins as [this guide](https://code.google.com/p/tlc5940arduino/wiki/ArduinoDiecimilaHardwareSetup).  The ADCs are assigned to different pins than the LED driver.  I found that the LED driver conflicts with the SPI communication interface according to the comment:

```
Tlc.init();  //interferes with other SPI
```

but I'm not sure what to do about it since if this is not called, the LED driver does not work.  It seems to be true, however, since if I comment out all of the LED driver related lines in my code, the ADCs work.

Also, I am using bit banging to communicate to the MCP3208.

Comment: You do realise the LED controller is not an SPI device?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that.  I am not treating it as such, but it is somehow interfering with the ADCs that are SPI devices.

Comment: Hmmm, I think I need more information about your set-up then. Are you using timers and PWMs to drive the LED driver? What does, exactly, Tlc.init() do please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code, you'll see that `tlc_config.h` contains options relating to the communication and connection with the TLC'. Simply edit the options within that file to suit your needs.

Comment: @Plan9: It's probably the intended way to solve the problem. Something I've noticed about Arduino libraries is that they don't always tend to be... self-contained.